# Разбить результат на тэги

Tags: php, xml

После парсинга в XML, все значения встают в свои тэги. Кроме тэга `<location></location>`, так как изначально, это текстовое поле, в котором в одну строку вводится несколько параметров - Страна, область, Город, Улица. На выходе получается, Россия, Московская область, город Пушкино, ул. Учинская. Но это категорически не подходит, так как `<location></location>` имеет вложенные тэги.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить задачу:
Есть результат в одну строку:

```
<location>
Россия, Московская область, город Пушкино, ул. Учинская
</location>
```

Нужно чтобы на выходе получалось:

```
<location>
<country>Россия</country>
<region>Московская область</region>
<district>Пушкино</district>
<street>Учинская</street>
</location>
```

Comment: Брать исходник, парсить и выводить в нужном формате. Каков вопрос - такой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теория:

```
print_r(explode(' ', 'Страна Область Город Улица'));
Array ( [0] => Страна [1] => Область [2] => Город [3] => Улица )
```

Практика:

```
<?
$data = 'Страна Область Город Улица';
$arr = explode(' ', $data);
?>
<location>
<country><?=$arr[0]?></country>
<region><?=$arr[1]?></region>
<district><?=$arr[2]?> </district>
<street><?=$arr[3]?></street>
</location>
```

Comment: Да, это подходит! Спасибо!